# HTML Select dropdowns are not working in android webview

Tags: android, html, webview, html-select

The Browser useragent version:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8C148 Safari/6533.18.5"
```

The basic HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Pages</title>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <select>
                <option>One</option>
                <option>two</option>
                <option>three</option>
                <option>four</option>
                <option>five</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This seems to be working on UIWebView(iPhone) and the native browsers. Only android webView is having the issue.Any help will be appreciated.The webview is a cordova activity

Comment: Please post your code in which you are trying to load this html in Android WebView.

Comment: @Bijeshp009 Can you elaborate on what the issue is?

Comment: Please visit this answer, it might help you stackoverflow.com/a/43497233/3086769

Comment: I know this is old one, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15960958/5702544) answer solve the issue for me.<br>
basically, make sure that you pass activity as Context to the WebView constructor.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_select
Problem Solved. :)

Comment: try to set the webView setJavaScriptEnabled to true

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @mattstow from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744437/html-select-box-not-showing-drop-down-arrow-on-android-version-4-0-when-set-with)

The Android Browser's rendering of `<select>`s is buggy and will remove the normal styling if a background or border is applied.

Since `<select>`s not looking like `<select>`s is a pretty big usability issue, your best bet is to not style them for this browser only.

Unfortunately, there's no pure CSS way of selecting/excluding the Android Browser, so I recommend you use Layout Engine (https://github.com/stowball/Layout-Engine), which will add a class of .browser-android to the `<html>` tag.

You could then style all `<select>`s except on Android Browser, like so:

```
html:not(.browser-android) select {
    background: #0f0;
    border: 1px solid #ff0;
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem related to the question. @Bijeshp009 is saying the select isn't working. Does the removal of styling on Android fix the select?